# Why does this custom comparator for sets in c++ behave like this?

Tags: c++

I have a set of structs where the struct is

```
struct sub_tree
{
    vector <int> nodes;
    int weight;
};
```

and the set along with the comparator function is

```
set <sub_tree, decltype (comp)*> s(comp);
bool comp (sub_tree a, sub_tree b)
{
    return (a.weight < b.weight);
}
```

Now when I input two structs with the same weight but different node vectors, like weight1 = 96 node1 = 5 and weight2 = 96 node2 = 6 it accepts only the first one in the set.
But if I use the following comparator then it accepts both the values.

```
set <sub_tree, decltype (comp)*> s(comp);
bool comp (sub_tree a, sub_tree b)
{
    return (a.weight <= b.weight);
}
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Look up "strict weak ordering". Your second version of the comparator function is wrong.

Comment: See [C++ named requirements: Compare -> `comp(a, b)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). The second version doesn't satisfy `compa(a, a) == false` for all `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison object for `set` must adhere to the [Compare named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). This means

> `equiv(a, b)`, an expression equivalent to `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`

i.e. if applying the function with the original and swapped order both return false, both values are considered the same.

The contract of `std::set::insert` specifies that no modification of the set takes place, if an equal object is already in the set. With the first comparison this is considered the case.

The second one does not adhere to the requirements of Compare though.

Let's assume the requirement cited above applies for your compare function: Pass 2 equal values `a1` and `a2`.

- `comp(a1, a2)` is `true`
- `comp(a2, a1)` is `true`

therefore according to the requirement of Compare `a1` and `a2` are not the same, which is a contradiction. Therefore the requirement is violated.

---

If you want to store multiple elements with the same weight in a set, you need to introduce a tie breaker or go with a [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)